# how to automake not recurse on packages?

Tags: automake

As every child in kindergarten knows, recursive make is a very bad thing.

I know very well how to properly handle large non-recursive but nicely distributed GNU Make projects through the use of include statements and directory stacks.

I am new to autotools and now I am trying to use the above knowledge, to do the same thing with autotools and Linux packages.

Automake manual says

"Automake provides sufficient cross-directory support 2 to enable you to write a single Makefile.am for a complex multi-directory package"

Great... but that is pointless isn't it??

I have of course multiple packages, and the very point of doing non-recursive automake setup, would be, to not recurse over those packages.  So, like in the case of GNU Make, have one top-level Makefile.am that includes fragments specific to individual packages.

But of course, I still want multiple packages, just like I normally would with a (bad) recursive setup.

Replacing bad recursive setup with a good non-recursive setup, should mean, leave everything else as is, not "replace all packages with one big package".

Is it possible to have non-recursive automake setup, without destroying the previous goals and targets that were found in the previous recursive setup?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you would prefer [Karel's approach to non-recursive `automake`](http://karelzak.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/non-recursive-automake.html) rather than [mine](https://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/automake/nonrecursive.html).

In general, to answer your question is to figure out what you mean with the word "package", because `make` has no such concept. If you mean what is often also called "module", i.e. a subdirectory in which source code and build files both reside, yeah it's definitely possible to do so with non-recursive `automake` done Karel's way.

If you're referring to something that can be **redistributed** separately and then combined together to build, then the answer is no, there is no such way to do so in `automake`, because the whole point of having a single build tree is that you have a single distributed package, to the point that `make dist` will create the compressed tarball for you.